# React Native : Return conditional Statement in View

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile-application

I'm facing a weird problem. In my react native app I have conditions that render the `View` and `ScrollView`. The problem is the false statement shows first before the true statement, so I have example below let say the `PinCodeVisible.showPinLock is true` so the `Pincode` should shown not the false statement which is the text. My problem is it shows first the false statement which is the `text` and then after it loads the true statement which is `pincode` , I just want to disregard the `text` under the false statement since it is false,

why It shown even it is false statement?
Did I missed something?

```
const [PinCodeVisible, setPin] = useState({ PINCodeStatus: "choose", showPinLock: false });

React.useEffect(() => {
setPin({ showPinLock: true});   //let say the pincode is true
 }, [])


return (
    <View style={styles.container} >
        {PinCodeVisible.showPinLock === true ? (

            <PINCode
                // modalVisible={modalVisible}
                status={PinCodeVisible.PINCodeStatus}
                touchIDDisabled={true}
                finishProcess={() => _finishProcess()}
                timeLocked={5000}
            />
        ) :
            <ScrollView style={styles.container}> //this scrollview shown first event the statement is true
                <Text>This text will show before the true statement above</Text>  // it should not shown because the statement is true
            </ScrollView>}
    </View>
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  }
```

Comment: Please check if you're able to get the value from PinCodeVisible. Is PinCodeVisible a component?

Comment: @KushalDesai I've added `PinCodeVisible` above and how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the following things,

1. Here if you want to display a true statement on page load then must set true as an initial value of your state only not required to set in useEffect.

`const [pinCodeVisible, setPin] = useState({ PINCodeStatus: "choose", showPinLock: true });`

2. If you want to update an object then you can update using the spread operator.

`setPin({ ... pinCodeVisible, showPinLock: true});`

3. In the render method you can use the conditional operator as below

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {(pinCodeVisible.showPinLock && (
        <PINCode
          finishProcess={() => _finishProcess()}
          status={pinCodeVisible.PINCodeStatus}
          timeLocked={5000}
          touchIDDisabled={true}
        />
      )) || (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
          <Text>This text will show before the true statement above</Text>
        </ScrollView>
      )}
    </View>
   );
```